# How to edit objects in a layout

Tags: android

I'm using frame layout to put 2 layout to store 2 page of objects, and add a button to change the page
(I'm not sure are this way is good. Maybe tell me what is better way)

But I can't hide the layout. I don't know how group up objects in the layout and hide them all.

---

EDIT: (sorry about my english)

I gonna follow this [Crossfading Two Views](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html)
the example is using
object_id.setVisibility(View.GONE);
to hide one object, but I want to hide a group of object

Honestly, I have no thing done. I am learning it and I didn't finish all the object what I need. I only created a button.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_weapon:
            changeWeapon();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_about:
            openAbout();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your snapshot. Also show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the parent `View` or `ViewGroup` (i.e. layout) and that will hide all attached children.

Comment: OMG, yeah, it should be works! I have no idea last time I got a error! Thank you and I hope I have no disturb you. It works now.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you're saying.  Are you seeing an issue with a specific version of Android?

Comment: Don't care about that. I fixed it and thank you so much for helping~ Thanks a lot!